# Why isn't my footer inheriting the width from the container?

Tags: html, css

As you may have noticed, the container has a width of 80% right . The header did inherit that 80% of width , but the footer is just giving me a big headache . When i put width:inherit on the footer; it didn't look anything like the width of the parents . Any advice on how to fix this .

Thank you

**html**

```
<body>
    <section class="container">
        <header>
            <h2 id="title"><a href="main.html">~<br> ~</a></h2>
        </header>
        <section class="product-container">
            <div>
                <img src="Images/Products/~.jpg" alt="Reload page.">
                <a href="#">All Day</h></a>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
            </footer>
        </section>
    </section>
</body>
```

**css**

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
    background-color: white;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px blue solid;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    /*background-color: aliceblue;*/
}

header {
    /*border: 1px red solid;*/
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    width: inherit;
    z-index: 1;
}

.product-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 13.5%;
    width: 80%;
    transform: translate(13.5%, 4%);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
    border: 1px red solid;
    text-align: center;

footer {
    height: 100px;
    width: inherit;
    transform: translateX(-25%);
    background-color: #010e16;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -12vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, you're using `<section>` tags incorrectly. Use a `<div>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is some issues with the formatting of your code. `<footer>`, I think, is accidentally wrapped in the product container. Also, width will take up 100% of the parent's width by default so if you specify 'inherit' on the child elements, it will cover 80% of the parent's 80% width if that makes sense. You just need to set the parent to 80% and let the children elements inherit that naturally. Here is some basic boiler plate for you to plug your content into that I think covers your use case:

```css
.container {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.product-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
}


/* just pretty colors */

.container>* {
  background: teal;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <header>
    HEADER
  </header>

  <section class="product-container">
    BODY
  </section>

  <footer>
    FOOTER
  </footer>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be so helpfull to see the code working on snippet, but what I think you might be having problems with, its the measure that you are using.

If you set the width of the footer to 80%, it will cover the 80% of the width of the screen, which is the body. This is because the percetage takes the father as a 100% width to set the width of the children, and it will be relative depending of the width of the parent.

So lets say that your parent its the footer, who has a width of 80% (relative to the body), then you place a div inside of the footer, that has a inherited width (80%). As the width that the div inside the footer its 80% because its the same of the parent, then this child div will have a 80% width over the 100% of the footer width, so the 80% width of this child wont be as long as the 80% width of the footer.

Let me know if this is solve your question or not.

Answer (score -1):

Try `width: 100%` in the footer css

Comment: An answer that starts with "Try" and doesn't go on to explain why that should be tried, or what effect is being sought is more of a comment. Explain why you think that will fix the problem and how it will fix the problem.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry. I was thinking that was sufficient to solve the problem. It works but I was a bit too short

Comment: @mferre It didn't work . I'm still trying to figure it out , but thanks for the suggestion .